# How to align text horizontally across vertical stacked buttons/list-items which might have 2-3 lines

Tags: html, css, html-table, css-grid

I'm trying to create a layout which is basically a table/css-grid which auto aligns text horizontally across multiple rows. The rows/list-items should be clickable and tabbable via tabindex and have some border and alternating backgrounds.

[image]

Although the text in the columns is the same in this example it won't be in the actual application. There might be a longer number in the first column, a shorter in the second, a longer in the third or even some text, so I need the layout to auto align those column widths. Red lines are just for illustration.

This is no problem as long as I'm only having one row of content within the list-item but how can I solve this problem when I'm having multiple rows? If this was a table layout what I need would be grouping two `<tr>`'s together in terms of tabindex/focus, onclick and visuals.

I could group them with a `display: contents;` container around them and still style them via `.contents-selector > *` in terms of the background and the border I guess, but I can't make it tabbable or clickable on the `.contents-selector` class.

Maybe there is a whole different approach to this, I'm not thinking about. I can of course achieve my layout with some hacky stuff like using tables for the layout, `position: absolute;` on the longer text and `<br>`'s on another column etc. while having the tabindex and onclick on the tr although I wouldn't know how many lines I get and how many `<br>`'s I would need but that can't be the right solution to this problem.

**Edit:** Solution was the usage of `tbody`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76546055/1900980

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a simple html `table` for this and `put each row or row-groups inside a` tbody`.  you can now use the` tbody`to style or set`onclick`listeners or`tab-index`

```css
table,
tr,
td
{
    border: 1px solid gray;
}

table tbody:nth-child(even)
{
    background-color: aqua;
}
```

```html
    <table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Lorem.</td>
            <td>Qui?</td>
            <td>Consequatur!</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>

    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Lorem, ipsum.</td>
            <td>Neque, enimssssssssssssss.</td>
            <td>Aut, vitae!</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Lorem, ipsum.</td>
            <td>Neque, enim.</td>
            <td>Aut, vitae!</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Lorem.</td>
            <td>Qui?</td>
            <td>Consequatur!</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: The problem with this example is, that the `div.row` isn't a row but the column. So I would have the same problem just rotated, without any grouping around the list-items.

Comment: Yes I can get the layout with a table. My problem is that might need to group two `<tr>`'s together for them to have one shared `tabindex` and `onclick` and consistent styling in terms of alternate coloring, borders etc. As shown in the picture. I need the conditional line of text to be part of the list item.

Comment: Data is coming from the database and it can vary in length by quite a bit of characters. HTML is rendered on the server via PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Solution was to use one `tbody` per "row", which could include two `tr`'s. `tbody` can be used with tabindex and onclick and the styling is possible via selectors like `nth-child`, `first-child` and `last-child`.